# Run socket.io server in C#

Tags: c#, socket.io

I'm running a socket.io server and client locally. The code I'm running to create the server with `node` is:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('message', function(data) {
      socket.broadcast.send(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
});

console.log('listening on port 3000');
```

The client html page that sends the messages is the following:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

        setInterval(function() {
            var timestamp = new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
            socket.send(timestamp + ", " + "<Test message>");
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have the data sent to the socket available to C# so want to run the socket.io server in C# rather than Javascript. I can then have access to whatever is sent by the clients to the server.

Any idea how this could be implemented? Is there any other way of sending data from a webpage running locally to a socket server in C# to print it on the console etc? There is quite a lot of data and it's realtime, so it probably needs to be a socket of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spike Engine](http://www.spike-engine.com/) actually implements a socket.io 0.9 server. It isn't a pure socket.io server per say, as there's an additional layer to allow binary data to be send back and forth as well, which wasn't available for socket.io 0.9, but we will be porting it to socket.io 1.0 in the near future, which greatly simplifies things.