# Is there a way to create a Socket.IO Server in C#?

Tags: c#

I am setting up a C# Console Application and I need to add a Socket.IO Server in that project, as far as I've researched there's no package for Socket.IO server in C#. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run socket.io server in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417992/run-socket-io-server-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hav a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server)

Comment: It's not a duplicate since the answer of that post remits to another package which has no server support.

Answer (score -2):

There is a very simple way to start a socket server in C#. It already provides a built in facility for this.

Refer a sample [implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server)

You just need to do

```
        varserver = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 80);    
        server.Start();    
        var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Comment: `Socket.IO` is a protocol. This goes *way beyond* a simple TCP socket.